# Access class template variable outside of class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class like this:

```
template<char _character>
class Foo
{
    ...
public:
    static const char character = _character;
};
```

Is there a way I can access the _character parameter outside the class, without the static to forward it? Something like `Foo::_character`.

Comment: I believe the standard containers wouldn't have the `value_type` member if you could.

Comment: Did you try Foo<my_char>::character?

Comment: @John: He's not asking whether it's possible to use the given static member, but if it's possible to get the applied template parameter without such facilities (the original `_character`).

Comment: Ah.  So maybe a <code>template<char c> get_foo_char(Foo<c> my_foo){return c;}</code> and hope/rely on the compiler to automatically match it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no, you can't.

`_character` is the template parameter, and is unknown until you instantiate the template.

After instantiation `_character` is no longer a member of your concrete instantiation, but rather the 
char you passed in is.

By creating `static const char character = _character;` you are creating a *char data member* which is *dependent* on the template parameter used to instantiate your class template.

You can now access said data member from an instantiated class template:

```
typedef Foo<'c'> CFoo;
std::cout << CFoo::character << std::endl;
```

Once you instantiate the class template, `Foo<'c'>::_character` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern matching:

```
template<typename T>
struct get_character;
template<char _character>
struct get_character<Foo<_character> > {
    static const char character = _character;
};
```

To use:

```
get_character< Foo<'a'> >::character
```